# Limiting $scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a multi-page AngularJS web application that serves as an analytics dashboard. I am currently using $scope to create variables so I can display some of the data dynamically on the HTML pages. Instead of creating $scope variables that will be global no matter what page a user is visiting I would like to limit the variables to their page and their page only. Since I am new to Angular I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$scope variables aren't global; they are specific to the controller. If you want variables that are specific to each page, put a controller on each page (and don't add a controller to a parent element since its scope will be inherited).

Answer (score 1):

Create seperate controller for each page. $scope in nt global. Its scope is limited to its controller

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope` is based on the controller, so to make stuff specific to a page do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('pageOne', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.forThis = "value for page one controller";
}]);

app.controller('pageTwo', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.forThis = "value for page two controller";
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzpp3ve3/

Comment: Since the poster is under the impression that $scope is global, it's extremely likely that he has a controller attached to a very high-level element (like `<body>`) whose `$scope` properties are being inherited by pretty much every other element. He would also need to get rid of that.

Comment: @AlvinThompson, yes it would just be a matter of putting the scopes in the correct controller relevant to his pages.

Comment: I have a controller for each page. For some reason I was under the impression that the $scope would hold values globally. I just ran tests and it works as you guys have said! Thanks :)

Comment: @Niraj: One more thing to be aware of: even if you use the same controller on two separate pages, they each will have their own separate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to invoke the [controllerAs](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax. Whether you do this in your routing or in your HTML elements is not relevant. But this allows you to use namespacing in Angular. In the following example I'm assuming you're invoking the ng-controller directive on your HTML elements.

Your HTML would be:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as my">
  {{my.var}}
</div>
```

And your controller would be

```
.controller("MyController", function() {
   this.var = "hello world";
}
```

This has been implemented since Angular 1.3.X, if I'm correct. $scope is in fact polluting since it adds to the prototypical inheritance chain controllers use. I.e. child controllers **do** **inherit $scope** variables from their parents.